# Does UIView object with zero size occupy considerable memory?

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview

To customize the tableView Cell, I am inserting a dummy backgroundview with zero rect.
So the question is does UIView object with zero rect occupy memory ?,  is it a waste of memory ?

Answer (score 1):

All objects take memory. At a minimum there is the space needed to hold every instance variable of the class (and all of its superclasses). Some classes may allocate additional memory based on their implementation.

In this case, a zero rect view added to a few rows in a table is so negligible there is no real reason to even think about it.